# chrt(): "failed to set pid XXX's policy" on one machine, but not others

Tags: ubuntu, scheduling

I have several Linux machines, all of them running the same kernel (Ubuntu 12.04, `3.5.0-45-generic`). On one of them, I am unable to use `chrt` at all. If I attempt to use it on a new process, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo chrt -f 1 ls
chrt: failed to set pid 0's policy: Operation not permitted
```

If I attempt to use it on an existing process, I get a similar error:

```
$ stress -c 1 &
[1] 3929
$ sudo chrt -f -p 1 3929
chrt: failed to set pid 3929's policy: Operation not permitted
```

I'm operating as super-user so I should have `CAP_SYS_NICE`, and I am indeed able to `nice` or `renice` a process; I just can't adjust its real-time properties.

This behavior is unique to this one machine; the behavior persists through reboot and launching a new shell in a stripped environment (`env -i bash --noprofile --norc`).

If I attempt to run this command on any of the other machines (all the same distribution, but some with different hardware) it succeeds as expected.

The closest to an explanation I found was [this Google groups posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/WRCyh_pE3qA) in which someone asserted that the same problem was because of the use of cpuset. I was unable to find any elaboration. I have previously done some work on this machine  with thread affinities (`pthread_setaffinity_np()`), taskset, cpusets, isolcpus, etc. However, I don't know how any of those could still be causing this behavior, since I'm not explicitly setting any priorities, and e.g. `taskset -p $$` shows the full set of CPUs (as expected). Also, I've double-checked that I'm not still running with any CPUs isolated (`cat /proc/cmdline`).

Is there any configuration I'm overlooking? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**
As per @bersch's suggestion, I'm including excerpts from running `strace`.
On a working machine setting to priority 13:

```
sched_setscheduler(2475, SCHED_FIFO, { 13 }) = 0 # PID 2475
sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, { 13 }) = 0 # ls
```

The same on the broken machine:

```
sched_setscheduler(6248, SCHED_FIFO, { 13 }) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted) # PID 6248
sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, { 13 }) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted) # ls
```

This is exactly what I would expect from the error messages.

Comment: you could compare /boot/config-* settings if you really run the same kernel and for example check for `sched_setscheduler` with `strace -f chrt -f 1 ls`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The contents are indeed identical. I updated the original post with the strace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Groups post and @bersch's suggestion to look for the `sched_setscheduler` call directly (instead of the `chrt` command-line wrapper) got me to an answer: it was indeed because of my use of cpuset. I had forgotten that [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) is used to support [cpusets](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cpusets.txt).

A search for `sched_getscheduler` and `cgroup` turned up a ton of hits, including

http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7012851

At any rate, I currently have no need for cgroups at all, so I just disabled it:

```
sudo service cgconfig stop
```

Now everything works as expected.

**Edit**
To get the change to persist after reboot, I had to comment out the contents of `/etc/cgconfig.conf` as well.

Comment: what's the name of the package in Ubuntu that uses cgconfig?

Comment: @bersch: According to `dpkg`, it was  `libcgroup1`, though I think I installed that as a dependency of something higher level, e.g. `cpuset`.

Comment: you get the info with `dpkg -S /etc/cgconfig.conf`

Comment: ... that was what I meant by "According to `dpkg`"

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The following command fixed it:

```
sysctl -w kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=-1
```

Source: https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-security/2011-04/msg00015.html

Comment: This solved the problem for me.

Comment: also solved it for me. but i don't understand why it solved it for me. in older rhel-6 (centos) i think i did not have this issue. on newer rhel-8 (rocky) i did need this solution.