# How to set a process’s sched method to fifo and priority when cgroup are on?

Tags: scheduling, cgroups

I’m using CentOS 6.6, I want to set the sched method of my kvm VM to FIFO with priority 1. 
First, I use chrt and get error:

```
chrt(): "failed to set pid XXX's policy"
```

I find here:
[chrt(): "failed to set pid XXX's policy" on one machine, but not others](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114643/chrt-failed-to-set-pid-xxxs-policy-on-one-machine-but-not-others)
and use

```
sudo service cgconfig stop
```

then I can use chrt to set it.

Here, https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPUTuning ,the vcpusched of cputune can do it. But my libvirtd version is 0.10.2 and the vcpusched is offered Since 1.2.13. Since libvirtd can offer this, I think I can do this manually, too.

But in cgroup file system, cpu | cpuset subdir, libvirt/qemu/$(domain)/vcpu0, I can't find sched policy.

So, what should I do if I don’t stop cgroups to set process sched method and priority?