# chrt fails to set policy - Invalid argument

Tags: linux, scheduling

This happens both on Fedora and Garuda. Here are example error messages:

```
$ sysctl kernel/sched_deadline_period_min_us kernel/sched_rt_period_us kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
kernel.sched_deadline_period_min_us = -1
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = -1
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = -1
$ chrt --deadline -P 50000 --pid 0 2236118
chrt: failed to set pid 2236118's policy: Invalid argument
```

```
$ sysctl kernel/sched_deadline_period_min_us kernel/sched_rt_period_us kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
kernel.sched_deadline_period_min_us = -1
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = -1
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = -1
# chrt -d -P 50000 0 yes
chrt: failed to set pid 0's policy: Invalid argument
```

As you can see, the solution found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114643/chrt-failed-to-set-pid-xxxs-policy-on-one-machine-but-not-others) is not working. The `cgconfig` service doesn't exist, so the second answer is irrelevant. Permissions aren't a problem either
I ran `strace` on both calls. They both fail at `sched_setattr`:

```
sched_setattr(2236118, {size=56, sched_policy=SCHED_DEADLINE, sched_flags=0, sched_nice=0, sched_priority=0, sched_runtime=50000, sched_deadline=50000, sched_period=50000, sched_util_min=0, sched_util_max=0}, 0) =-1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
sched_setattr(0, {size=56, sched_policy=SCHED_DEADLINE, sched_flags=0, sched_nice=0, sched_priority=0, sched_runtime=50000, sched_deadline=50000, sched_period=50000, sched_util_min=0, sched_util_max=0}, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

I have also checked [the manpages for sched_setattr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setattr.2.html). According to them, all the parameters are acceptable.

`chrt` versions:

```
chrt from util-linux 2.38
chrt from util-linux 2.37.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `kernel.sched_deadline_period_min_us` to 50 has solved the issue